# How to install Windows 7 in Dual Boot with Ubuntu (Ubuntu pre-installed)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I want to ask how can I install Windows 7 Home Premium in Dual Boot with pre-installed Ubuntu.
I`ve never opened my laptop, so the Ubuntu Set-up is not made.

Comment: You'll definitely have to go through the Ubuntu setup first, especially if this is your only computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the info needed for that:

http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony